# Angular router does not work as expected

Tags: angular, routes

I have some question about Angular5 router, I generated root routes like following.

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path:'',
        loadChildren:'./feature1/index#Feature1Module'
    },
    { 
        path:'**',
        component: ErrorComponent
    }
]
```

And the way I compose app.component.html is like following.

```
<div>
  <header></header>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

Then, I have generated second routes inside Feature1 like below.

```
export const Feature1Routes = [
    {
        path: '', redirectTo: 'feature1', pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path:'feature1',
        component: Feature1Component
    }
]
```

From this composition of routes, I expected that

```
<header> 
<feature1>
<footer>
```

However, what I look now is

```
<header>
<footer>
<feature1>
```

Does anyone have some any idea about this situation? This is very weird.. :(

Comment: Can you build a plunker or stackblitz that demonstrates the issue? My first guess would be a styling (CSS) problem?

Comment: I listened to your lecture in pluralsight. Thank you for good lecture. I will try to reproduce this later sometime, not right now. if I do quick question, what kind of css can have effect on route configurations?

Comment: I can only imagine this to happen when the HTML is invalid, but Angular should report that as an error anyway.

Comment: To be exact, the <router-outlet> element should be rendered in the HTML too. The router does not replace the router outlet, it uses it as a reference point and inject elements next to it in the DOM. So if the router outlet isnt rendered, then most likely there is something wrong in your configuration. Please provide a small reproduction

Comment: Glad you liked them. You know how CSS is, any little thing off and it could display the content in the wrong place (nothing to do with the routes per se). But as the others have said, it could also be a problem in the Html or a syntax error somewhere. Is there anything displayed in the console?

Comment: Thank you for you guys kind explanation, I think I need to make toy example soon, and let you know.

Comment: Here is a simple example of how CSS can "misplace" elements. Notice that there is no routing going on here ... but it still puts things in the wrong places: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rfdxuy

Comment: Yes, my problem was issued by CSS. especially, because of 'float'. After removing 'float', it works as expected. In your example, also float...  I kind of spent a lot time on it. I would like to learn CSS step by step but it is not easy. Anyway, thank you so much!!

Comment: I looked at the <router-outlet> directive a little deeply. There was some output named 'activate' and 'deactivate', From very simple thinking, if the router-outlet is activated, that activate EventEmitter would be emitted, so I tried this way to see what happen
<router-outlet  (activate)="activate()"></router-outlet>, but nothing happens in activate() method.. is this does not make sense? :)